# Appearance of Qt/GTK-based apps on other platforms

Tags: qt, gtk

I was wondering why some apps that are written in either GTK or Qt do not blend seamlessly with the visual theme of the platform they are running on, if that platform has not been written using that toolkit, i.e. a Qt-based app running on a Gnome-based OS.

I myself develop Qt apps on Ubuntu and when I compile and run them, that look **exactly** like the GTK-based apps that ship by default. I know that Qt is simply a wrapper for the existing native libraries for whatever platform it's on, so I would assume that the GTK theme is being rolled into my app when I compile, and the same would be true if I build it on a KDE-based platform.

Can anyone confirm if this is the case, or if it's something else entirely?

Comment: I don't think Qt is a wrapper - are you thinking of WX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experience with Qt has been pretty much similar (the Qt app inherits the style of the platform/OS), with the one big exception.  If my Qt app has it's own style information, that will take precedent over the inherited style.  (See the [Qt Styles Example](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-styles.html).)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem developing apps for KDE. As a solution I use [setStyle(QString styleName)](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qapplication.html#setStyle-2) to override default qt style selection